# How to join 2 dataframe on year and month in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframe and I want to join them on the basis of month and year from a date without creating extra columns:

example :

df1 :

```
date_1      value_1
2017-1-15    20
2017-1-31    30
2016-2-15    20
```

df2:

```
date_2      value_2
2017-1-1    30
```

then get result as below i.e. merged on the basis of month and year.

```
date_1      value_1 value_2
2017-1-15    20     30
2017-1-31    30     30
2016-2-15    20
```

Comment: Create merge key using the year-month, then merge

Comment: Are your date columns datetime dtypes?

Comment: Thanks wen, solved

Comment: Given pandas robust datetime tools, I don't think it's ever necessary to pull components out of a datetime.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a rudimentary but effective solution:

```
res = pd.merge(df1.assign(grouper=df1['date_1'].dt.to_period('M')),
               df2.assign(grouper=df2['date_2'].dt.to_period('M')),
               how='left', on='grouper')

print(res)

      date_1  value_1 grouper     date_2  value_2
0 2017-01-15       20 2017-01 2017-01-01     30.0
1 2017-01-31       30 2017-01 2017-01-01     30.0
2 2016-02-15       20 2016-02        NaT      NaN
```

You can then remove unwanted columns:

```
res = res[['date_1', 'value_1', 'value_2']]
```

Comment: This works brilliantly while trying to merge multiple sources with dirty data. Great little snippet!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using lambda functions:

```
pd.merge(df,df2, left_on=df['date_1'].apply(lambda x: (x.year, x.month)),
         right_on=df2['date_2'].apply(lambda y: (y.year, y.month)),
         how='outer')[['date_1','value_1','value_2']]

    date_1      value_1   value_2
0   2017-01-15    20        30.0
1   2017-01-31    30        30.0
2   2016-02-15    20        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

### `map`

```
mapping = dict(zip(df2.date_2.dt.to_period('M'), df2.value_2))
df1.assign(value_2=df1.date_1.dt.to_period('M').map(mapping))

      date_1  value_1  value_2
0 2017-01-15       20     30.0
1 2017-01-31       30     30.0
2 2016-02-15       20      NaN
```