# Create Pandas DF column based on values from an exiting column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df showing item sales sales at the item level. Sales occur each week of the year, with a corresponding date (not all items have sales each week of the year). Df looks similar this:

```
date         week_of_year itemNbr   itemDesc  storeNbr   Sales  
2021-06-29   23           1234      shampoo   123        100   
2021-07-06   24           1234      shampoo   123        500   
2021-07-09   25           1234      shampoo   180        0     
2020-07-10   24           1234      shampoo   123        50
2020-01-05   1            1325      bowl      129        10   
2019-01-01   1            1325      bowl      129        100
```

I need a column showing an items sales during the same time (week of year) a year ago, at the same store number. So it should look like this:

```
date         week_of_year itemNbr   itemDesc  storeNbr   Sales  YearAgo
2021-06-29   23           1234      shampoo   123        100    NaN
2021-07-06   24           1234      shampoo   123        500    50
2021-07-09   25           1234      shampoo   180        0      NaN
2020-07-10   24           1234      shampoo   123        50     NaN
2020-01-05   1            1325      bowl      129        10     100
2019-01-01   1            1325      bowl      129        100    NaN
```

I've tried something like:

```
df['LastYear'] = df.groupby([df['week_of_year'],df['date'].dt.year,df['storeNbr'], 
df['itemNbr']],sort=False)['Sales'].shift(-1)
```

but the previous year values that populate in the new column don't appear to be accurate, as some items with no prior year history are populating with sales values. I appreciate any help here!

Comment: You've grouped by `year`. There's no way if each year is in a separate group that `groupby shift` would give you the previous year's values. Since `groupby shift` will only shift values _within_ the group.

Comment: You could make a copy with `date` that has a decremented year and join on `date`, `week_of_year` and `storeNbr`. [Here is how to restrict the join on a subset of the date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992388/16343464).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out guys. I was able to get the desired result using @HenryEcker suggestion and removing the year from the groupby and shifting by 1 instead of -1.

Comment: I am glad you could get it to work. Could you provide your solution as an answer to your own question so that it can benefit to others?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired result by amending this line of code:

```
df['LastYear'] = 
df.groupby([df['week_of_year'],df['date'].dt.year,df['storeNbr'], 
df['itemNbr']],sort=False)['Sales'].shift(-1)
```

To this, removing the year from the groupby and changing the shift to 1 instead of -1:

```
df['LastYear'] = 
df.groupby([df['week_of_year'],df['storeNbr'], 
df['itemNbr']],sort=False)['Sales'].shift(1)
```

Comment: The shift value should be -1, not 1. Also, you can just use the column names in your groupby: `df.groupby(['week_of_year', 'storeNbr', 'itemNbr'], sort=False)`. Also, be careful of your formatting, your code is currently multiline and wouldn't work if copy-pasted.